# What specifically allows app attribution to dispaly on Facebook posts from iOS apps?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the app attribution (app name) to display on all posts to Facebook from my app using the following code:

```
-(void)shareToFacebook
{
    if( [m_selectedPhotos count] > 0 )
    {
        NSMutableArray *photos = [NSMutableArray array];

        for( int i = 0; i < [m_selectedPhotos count]; i++ )
        {
            NSNumber *selected = [m_selectedPhotos objectAtIndex:i];
            if( selected.boolValue == YES )
            {
                UIImage *selectedImage = [m_scrollView imageViewAtIndex:i].image;
                FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
                photo.image = selectedImage;
                photo.userGenerated = YES;

                [photos addObject:photo];
            }
        }

        FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
        content.photos = photos;
        content.hashtag = [FBSDKHashtag hashtagWithString:@"#PosePro"];

        [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                     withContent:content
                                        delegate:nil];
    }
}
```

The code posts correctly to Facebook, however the app attribution which links to the App Store page does not display along with the posts. Does anyone know how to enable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

here's my 2 cents:

a. have you setup the info.plist according to Facebook iOS guideline: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

b. your Facebook app needs to be reviewed by Facebook